# Configure Leak Period to match sprints

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to configure SonarQube Leak Period to match our sprints (14 days). We don't release after each sprint, and our branch is always "develop" so I can't key off of a release.

I know that I can configure X number of days, but I don't want a rolling account over a 14 day period... I would like it to do the delta by comparing each of the 14 days to Day 1. So, Day 2 <> Day 1, Day 3 <> Day 1, etc. Then on the 15th day it would reset for the start of the new sprint.

How can I configure SonarQube to always start the leak period with the start of a new sprint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't want a rolling 14-day period, you'll have to manually re-configure to the start date of the new sprint every 2 weeks.

Alternately, you could jigger your versions to something like

- 3.14-sprintAlpha
- 3.14-sprintBeta
- ...

And use the `previous_version` leak period setting.